# UISwipeGestureRecognizer throws off EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, exc-bad-access, uiswipegesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I have a view that I'm designing with XIB file, and writing a regular class that inherits from UIView, as normal. I need to add swipe functionality to the view. First, yes, I've user interaction enabled, both in IB and in `viewDidLoad` method as `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` just in case something overrides IB.

I am creating my swipe gesture recognizer this way in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiper = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiper];
```

where I have:

```
- (void)swiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    self.swipeAction();    
}
```

When I run my app and do a swipe gesture, I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

[image: error]

The interesting part is that I have a breakpoint on `self.swipeAction();` line, that doesn't even get hit. I immediately get this error. Sometimes I just get bad access error, and sometimes I get very weird errors such as:

```
-[UIViewAnimationState swiped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96263f0
```

You can replace `UIViewAnimationState` with `NSString` too as I also saw that one too. When I get that in the output, I'm getting SIGABRT instead of EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What could cause this behavior? I've tried creating a gesture recognizer on IB too, with the same results.

The behavior is totally indeterministic; I try the exact same thing two times, once I get bad access, then straight after it, in the second run, I get a sigabrt.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing? Or is it an indicator of a serious memory leak somewhere else (which shows itself up obsessively only on swipe gesture recognizers and nowhere else)? Tried both emulator and real device, with different iOS versions on the emulator. No luck, all the same.

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: Have you tried to add the direction recognizer property?
[swiper setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];

Comment: The errors suggest that the target of the gesture recognizer (self) is being deallocated even though the gesture recognizer (and possibly the view) are still alive.

Comment: Can you call a method using dot notation? Otherwise the code seems to be fine.

Comment: @Tchelow added it, nothing changed.

Comment: @SorinCioban it is a c-style-block object instance as a property of the object. typedef void (^actionBlock)(void); @property(nonatomic, copy) actionBlock swipeAction;

Comment: @rmaddy self is the View object, and it is not deallocated as it's active on the screen and responding to everything else perfectly without errors. i'm on ios5+/arc anyway.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu No, `self` is the view controller, not the view. Objects get deallocated under ARC, just like they do with MRC.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for that. i was meaning viewcontroller. it has other objects/subviews and lots of methods running smoothly at the moment of error. about arc, i was just mentioning that i'm not manually deallocating anything by mistake..

Comment: Have you tried to restart Xcode? Sometimes it goes crazy!
I didn't saw anything that you may have missed.

Comment: I have used the same code you used in a project here to test and it worked perfectly. I just had removed the line self.swipeAction();
Btw, are you sure about calling methods with ()? The common way in Objective-C is to use [self swipeAction];

Comment: @Tchelow yes, didn't help. see my previous comments for swipeAction